# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive

Tags: java, c#, ksoap2

I am trying to connect my Android APP development to a Web Service and cannot seem to capture the response (throws the above error); the snippet of my APP code, follows:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String URL = "https://MyDomain/Services/AccountManager.asmx";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME = parameters.get("METHOD_NAME");
    String ReturnValue;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    // addProperty for each KeyPair in the Parameters HashMap
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> parameter : parameters.entrySet()) {
        if (!parameter.getKey().startsWith("_") && parameter.getKey() != "METHOD_NAME") {
        request.addProperty(parameter.getKey() , parameter.getValue());
        }
    }

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        httpTransportSE.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        ReturnValue = soapPrimitive.getAttribute("StatusCode").toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ReturnValue = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

The error is thrown by the line

```
SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

I read a number of articles/posts which suggests changing the previous line, to the following line:

```
Object soapPrimitive = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
```

Whilst this does "workaround" the error, the return values from the service are then unnamed:

1. OK
2. 2119100
3. 278
4. E

... rather than, being in a usable "pairing";

```
response.getAttribute("AccountNumber") = 2119100
response.getAttribute("AccountBalance") = 278
response.getAttribute("StatusCode") = "E"
```

I do have control of the Web Service, so it's possible to make edits there, if that's the solution; a snippet of the C# code for the service:

```
[WebMethod(
    Description = "Account Lookup", 
    MessageName = "Account",
    EnableSession = false)]
public string Account(
    string PostCode, 
    string Surname, 
    out double? AccountBalance, 
    out string AccountNumber, 
    out string StatusCode)
    {
        // MY STUFF HERE
        AccountBalance = 50;
        AccountNumber = 123456;
        StatusCode = "A";
        Return "OK";
    }
```

The above is a significantly cut-down version of the actual service, which (for production) would return [for example] a complete breakdown of a financial transaction, with the opening balance, current balance, VAT, interest, discounts, etc., so keeping track of an unnamed indexed list will gradually become a maintenance nightmare.

[edit 22/02/2019]

I have changed (and simplified)the WebService so that it ONLY takes the INPUT values

```
[WebMethod(
    Description = "Account Lookup", 
    MessageName = "Account",
    EnableSession = false)]
public string Account(
    string PostCode, 
    string Surname)
```

.. and from within that method, I make the more in-depth call to a private method that handled the "out" parameters. The WebMethod then turns those parameters into a JSON string and return it. This (rather ugly method) worked, until I wanted to return an array of data, which dropped straight back to the original error.

... next step (as I cannot locate a working solution) will be to try the same with and XML response.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `envelope.getResponse()` call returns a collection of `SoapPrimitive`s.

Try something like

```
Vector responseVector = (Vector) envelope.getResponse();
for (Vector res : responseVector) {
    SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) res;
    // your code here using soapPrimitives
}
```

If the type of elements is still different than `SoapPrimitive`, there will be a new `Exception` and you can cast accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response and yes, that does indeed show that I have a collection of SoapPrimitives (one for each of the return parameters) but, watching the variables, as I am stepping through the code, there's still no mention of the parameter name, so this is pretty much the same as the "Object soapPrimitive" point in my original post.